# How to link records from multiple tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: properties table - (this will store information of properties) and an images table - (this table has a foreign key - `imgID` which references the `ID` from the properties table).
I need to link images to a particular property. So if the property ID is 1 it will be linked to all the images from the images table that have a  imagePublisherID of 1. How can I do something like this?

Edit: Heres some data from both tables:

Images:

[image]

Properties:

[image]

Desired Output:
If the `properties.ID = 1` - this will retrieve all the image records from the images table with an `imgID of 1`

Comment: Pictures and DESCRIBE are not safe - provide SHOW CREATE TABLE output as formatted text.

Comment: *if the property ID is 1 it will be linked to all the images from the images table that have a imagePublisherID of 1.* Unclear. Provide also some sampole data - current and desired.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: I've added some data and have also specified what I want to output

Answer (score 0):

add another column to your images table and name it for example `propertyID` and give it the property id.  So you can always access those images by the `propertyID`

Example:

```
properties table
+----------------------------
|id|title|description|
|1|blah|blah blah b|
------------------------------

images table
+---------------------------------------------
|id|image1|image2|propertyId|
|1|blah|blah blah b| 1                |
----------------------------------------------
```

i want now to access the images that belong to property 1.
`SELECT * FROM images WHERE propertyId='HERE YOU PUT THE PROPERTY ID'` then you get the images you want.

Answer (score 0):

When property ID is 1, for fetching the entire result

```
SELECT *
FROM properties AS P
LEFT JOIN images AS I ON P.ID = I.imagePublisherId
WHERE P.ID = 1
```

> In this query, I'm using `LEFT JOIN` assuming that there can be a possibility that for a given property images may have not been added till yet.

If you just want to fetch images of Property ID = 1,

```
SELECT *
FROM images AS I
WHERE I.imagePublisherId=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `INNER JOIN`?

> *The `INNER JOIN` keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.*[¹](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

**Code Syntax**

```
SELECT *
FROM properties
INNER JOIN images
ON properties.ID = images.imagepublisherId;
ORDER BY properties.title ASC
```

**INNER JOIN Chart**
[image: inner join]

Comment: So basically imagePublisherId is a FK to the ID field in the properties. This is so that we can uniquely identify each property from each other and also imagePublisherId references ID so it can retrieve all the relevant images that have the same imagePublisherId as properties.ID